# Why does my Go app fail with "no such file or directory" inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have a Go 1.18 app which runs without issues in my WSL2 Ubuntu, but fails to run in a Docker container with the error message `exec /app: no such file or directory`.

My Dockerfile (slightly adapted from another Go 1.12 app that works without issues) is:

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY source/*.go ./

RUN go build -o /app

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian11

COPY --from=build /app /app

USER nonroot:nonroot

CMD ["/app"]
```

Building it shows no errors. I tried adding `GOOS=linux` and `GOARCH=amd64` and building with `--platform linux/amd64` but it makes no difference (and should not be necessary I think?). I switched from Distroless to Debian, same issue.

The file `/app` exists (11 mb, `755`). `file /app` gives this output:

```
app: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, Go BuildID=UsV_orwX-S3Rwh16P1VH/6u2iHufDhnUYUkHBp0rE/2xn48wuW047ZRbQ7qPIy/ihQgooFxjsMgMzYGE-8h, not stripped
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. What is the issue here?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to not overwrite the directory you are building from -> `RUN go build -o /app/app`. Also, you may want to change `COPY --from=build /app /app` to `COPY --from=build /app/app /`

Comment: As @Daniel says, in your build container `/app` is a directory but in your final image `/app` is a file. The issue is almost certainly a confusion about which is which when building and then copying the application to the final image. Perhaps consider renaming your build directory to something else (e.g. `/build`) and then things might be a bit clearer.

Comment: Oh, I renamed my build output from a very project-specific name to "app" for my question and failed to notice the overlap, so this shouldn't be the actual issue. I took this approach from the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/#multi-stage-builds) btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be caused by using [go-ping/ping](https://github.com/go-ping/ping). Switching the build image to `golang:1.18` (not Alpine) and the final image to `gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11` fixes the issue.